# Installing Linux as the primary OS on HP Pavilion DV-7-1225-ez

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hardware

I have an old entertainment laptop, HP Pavilion DV7-1225ez, which I would like to turn into a portable development/learning computer.

I am now going through various linux distros to find the most suitable one - Ubuntu seems to be a good starting point. Some of the points that I am struggling in choosing the OS is due to the following:

- my laptop has a fingerprint scanner which works brilliantly on Windows. Is there a specific distro that I have to bear in mind in order to use this functionality or is this not possible with linux? (I want to use it simply to log-in/access the computer - like in the log-in page on Windows)
- I am planning on getting both SSD and RAM upgrades on this laptop in the coming weeks - can I implement these upgrades after switching to Linux or should I get the upgrades first and then switch? Would the choice of distro has any affect?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post (http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/how-to-get-your-fingerprint-reader-working-in-ubuntu) has a simple fingerprint scanner with a gui. It has precompiled binaries for Ubuntu (in other words you can install it in Ubuntu). You're asking for an opinion, which is probably off topic, but for your needs Ubuntu Mate would be a great choice. It is both light-weight and easy to use.

Comment: Thank you for the link! What do you think about the upgrades? Can I just install Ubuntu first and add the new SSD and RAM afterwards? Thanks

Comment: Oh yeah. In fact I'd recommend it. Although the ssd won't have an OS on it. Are you planning on dual-booting or just doing GNU/ Linux? If the former, clone your current drive then install. If the latter, simply make a bootable USB of your Linux distribution of choice, stuff the new ssd in, and go through the simple install process.

Comment: Also I do hope you made sure all the ram youll have in the machine is the same, and I mean more than just DDR3 or whatever. If it isn't the exact same type you'll run into all types of problems. Make sure it is and then make sure to run the built in Ubuntu memory check utility right after installation.

Comment: Many thanks for your comments - I am planning on running only Linux in order to ensure that it is the only OS I rely on while using that laptop. I will get the battery tomorrow (old one doesn't charge anymore) and I will install Ubuntu immediately. Next week I will receive the SSD and RAM (I am getting 2x4GB(max) so they will be the same.

Comment: I just realised, I will need to reinstall Ubuntu once I change the drive...

Comment: Wonderful. Sounds like you're good to go. Make to test out the different 'buntus first. Like I said I especially like Ubuntu Mate, especially with Compiz (look it up).